# Rejecting background in $B$-meson decay

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors

I want to reconstruct the $B$ mass from the [decay](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/BranchingRatio.action?parCode=S042&desig=16)
$$
B^0 \rightarrow K^{0*} \gamma \quad\text{ where }\quad K^{0*} \rightarrow K^{+} \pi^{-}
$$
and the equivalent antiparticle decay. A key element in the reconstruction is to detect the relevant photon $\gamma$.

Unfortunately there are a lot of photons whizzing around and there is a particular [decay](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/BranchingRatio.action?parCode=S042&desig=144) that seems to be contaminating our data: 
$$
B^0 \rightarrow K^{0*}\pi^0 \quad\text{ where }\quad \pi^0 \rightarrow \gamma \gamma
$$
One of these two photons misses the detector, and the other (detected) photon, together with the $K^{0*}$, is recorded as a $B^0 \rightarrow K^{0*} \gamma$ decay. But this will lead to a wrong mass reconstruction for the $B$ mass because of the energy carried away by the missed photon.

*How can I discard the photons from the pion decay background?*

---

My initial approach was: in the rest frame of the $B$, there is a 2 body decay from rest which means that $E_{K^{0*}}$ and $E_{\pi}$ ($E_{\gamma}$) are fixed. Conservation of energy and momentum lead to 
$$
E_{K^{0*}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{m_B^2-m^2+m_{K^{*}}}{m_B}c^2
$$
where $m$ is $m_{\pi}$ in the case of $B^0 \rightarrow K^{0*}\pi^0$, or $0$ ($m_{\gamma}$) for $B^0 \rightarrow K^{0*}\gamma$ .

Starting from the $E_{K^{0*}}$ in the lab frame and transforming it into the $B$ frame (feasible), I could check whether this is equal to the above formula with $m = m_{\pi}$ or $0$.

But the calorimeter resolution (ECAL) in most of the CERN experiments is about $\sim 100 MeV$ so it wouldn't be able to distinguish between a $135 MeV/c^2$ pion and a massless photon. I guess I could impose a cut to disregard all events with reconstructed $m>m_{\pi}$? Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with a monte carlo background? If you plot K0gamma invariant mass the contamination channel gamma within the peak, should be estimated from mc easily

Comment: cont: same for angular distributions

Comment: i agree with @annav, the branching ratios for the two decays are the same orders of magnitude, but for the background a photon must escape the detector, so it's probably much smaller than the signal? why can't you reconstruct the $B$ mass? Are you going to very high precision?

Comment: I am working with LHCb, the detector has actually a limited angular aperture so the probability that a photon misses it is not that small... I can reconstruct it but the Crystal Ball function that I am fitting probably has a longer tail that it should because it's trying to compensate for a secondary "peak" on the left reconstructed from $K^{*0}$ and $\gamma$ (from $\pi^0\rightarrow\gamma\gamma$)

Comment: If the pi0 has a large enough energy it will probably like a gamma. It is a different problem than a missing gamma from a pio.  If you stick to a plot with low energy gammas, the ones coming from the pi0 will not have the correct invariant mass of B. For high energy gammas you need a pi0gamma separation algorithm. I remember cms working on this , example http://cds.cern.ch/record/960994?ln=ka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Figure 2(a) of the 1fb$^{-1}$ $B^0 \to K^*\gamma$ branching fraction measurement paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0313v1

The inclusive $B^0 \to K^\pm\pi^\mp\pi^0$ background is modelled as a black dashed line. From the looks of this plot, the background contribution from $B^0 \to K^*\pi^0$ with a missing $\gamma$ is negligible. You have larger backgrounds to deal with. I suggest modelling it with generator-level events. If you can make an estimate of the expected yield for this background, and it comes out to much smaller than 1 event, then it's not worth the headache.